# Managing (routing between) two separate servers in the same web app

Tags: web-hosting, static-content, node-js, vhost

I am building a website, where the landing page and some other content is based on node, express, angular2 etc.

I want to have a subdomain (blog.mydomain.com) which runs [Hexo](http://hexo.io). On my development machine, I run `hexo server` to test the blog on `localhost:4000`. I can deploy to heroku by running `hexo generate -deploy`. So I have two questions - if I had a node app, where one of the sub-directories contained my current hexo project, how would I deploy it, as if I just uploaded the content, what would trigger hexo to run?

Secondly, how to I route from my main app, to the blog? I have seen a number of suggestions to use vhost with express. Would I run the two servers through different ports, and then just route `/blog` routes to`0.0.0.0:4000` for example?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run both node apps on different ports, I suggest using [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), which is a free and popular tool.
Then you'll need to route from the different domains or folder to different ports.
[NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/) is a very powerful tool, yet using [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) is much easier to configure and will do what you need.

Here's how you might want to set your routing:
`www.example.com:80` >> `localhost:80`
`blog.example.com:80` >> `localhost:4000`
OR
`www.example.com` >> `localhost:80`
`www.example.com\blog` >> `localhost:4000`

Comment: Thanks so much - that's really helpful. What does PM2 do?

Comment: PM2 lets you run multiple node processes in the background, keep them alive, monitor them, etc...